# Как в Laravel получить пароль из таблицы

Tags: php, laravel

При стандартной регистрации в Laravel пороли хранятся в хеш виде.Как мне как админу  получать пароль .Например для тестирования я хочу зайти под клиентом ?

Answer (score 1):

Воспользоваться классом laravelа - Crypter. 
Он может помочь расшифровать то, что сам зашифровал.

```
$decrypted_secret = Crypter::decrypt($secret); //Где $secret это hash.
```

Хотя многое зависит от того, как именно Вы хэшировали запись.

Comment: Почитайте, что такое хеш и шифр, и в чём их разница.

Answer (score 1):

В целях тестирования можно [авторизоваться под любым пользователем](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authentication#other-authentication-methods):

```
// Используя объект пользователя
Auth::login($user);
// Аутентифицировать и запомнить
Auth::login($user, true);

//=======================
// Аутентификация по ID
Auth::loginUsingId(1);
// Аутентифицировать и запомнить
Auth::loginUsingId(1, true);
```